# line bundles and jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective complex curve of genus 2 and $f : X \to Y$
a finite etale cover. Choose two distinct points A and B on $Y$
and let $\Sigma\subset X$ be the set of complex points $P$ such that
$f(P)$ is A or B. For any 
$x\in \Sigma$ choose an element $L(x) \in Pic(Y)[2]$. Does there exist an element $L\in Pic(X\times Y)[2]$ such that, for every
$x \in \Sigma$, the restriction of $L$ to $x\times Y = Y$
is equal to $L(x)$?

Angelo says that the restriction of $L$ to $x\times Y = Y$ is constant.
Is it so and why?

OK. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: What is the relationship between $x \in \Sigma$ and $L(x)$?

Comment: None. Another way to phrase the question: is the restriction map $Pic(X\timesY)[2] \ra Pic(\Sigma\times Y)[2]$ surjective?

Comment: Given an element $L\in Pic(X\times Y)[2]$, the associated map $X to Pic(Y)[2]$ is constant.

Answer (score 4):

If $Y$ is a complex projective algebraic variety, the Picard group $\operatorname{Pic}Y$ has the structure of an algebraic variety; if $X$ is another algebraic variety, any line bundle $L$ gives a regular map $X \to \operatorname{Pic}Y$ by sending $x \in X$ to the class of $L \mid x\times Y$. If $L$ is 2-torsion, then the map $X \to \operatorname{Pic}Y$ has image contained in $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)[2]$; but $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)[2]$ is finite, so if $X$ is connected, the map has to be constant.